# django "class name" object is showing instead of name

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

I would like to change the default behavior of how the admin recent changes sidebar displays the name of "objects" added.

In the recent actions module, it shows new objects as "MyModelName object"

I would like to change how these are named in the Admin. Ideally, I would like to be able to change it from "MyModelName object" to, as object.

I was thinking that **str** for my Profile model handled this, but it doesn't appear to. Any assistance is appreciated.

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class profile(models.Model):
    name= models.CharField(max_length=120)
    description = models.TextField(default='description default text')

    def _str_(self):
        return self.name
```

Answer (score 4):

You have used single `_` in the function name of `_str_` but it should be double `__`.

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```